# Making a CreateView in Django using kwargs from a different model template

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am not able to create the object `review` using the CreateView I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is a brief intro

**Intro:** My Order history page is where a user can see all the items that he/she has bought. In the Order history page I have a button that lets the buyer leave a review for the seller. Below is the button

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts:review' username=item.made_by pk=item.pk %}">
   <button class="text-success">Leave Review</button>
</a>
```

from here I get the items item.id and the sellers username

```
{% for item in order.items_in_this_order.all %} <!--models below -->
url(r'^(?P<username>[-\w]+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/review/$', views.ReviewCreate.as_view(), name='review'),
{% endfor %}
```

The url expresses correctly in the address bar when I click on leave a review. It then displays a form. where I enter `feedback`, `ratings`, `feedback_image`, `feedback_video` the rest of the fields are supposed to be made in the views.py. After I fill the form and hit submit. The url is still correct. But I get the below error

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/nikhil/10/review/
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_review.item_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/nikhil/10/review/
Django Version: 1.11
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_review.item_id
```

Below are the **views.py** this is inside the accounts app

```
class ReviewCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Review
    form_class = ReviewCreateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.review_from = self.request.user
        print(self.object.review_from) #This prints
        self.item = OrderItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        print(self.item) #This prints
        self.object.review_for = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        print(self.object.review_for) #This prints
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Below are the **models.py** for **Review models**

```
class Review (models.Model):
    review_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_from')
    review_for = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='review_for')
    item = models.ForeignKey(OrderItem, related_name='items')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    feedback = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    feedback_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
    feedback_video = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True)
    rating_choices = (
        ('1', 'One'), ('2', 'Two'), ('3', 'Three'), ('4', 'Four'), ('5', 'Five'),
        ('6', 'Six'), ('7', 'Seven'), ('8', 'Eight'), ('9', 'Nine'), ('10', 'Ten')
    )
    ratings = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=rating_choices)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Review from {} to {} for {}'.format(self.review_from, self.review_for, self.item.product)
```

Below are the **models.py** for **OrderItem** just in case

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='USD Price')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='items_in_this_order')
    date = models.DateField()
    time_from = models.TimeField()
    time_to = models.TimeField()
    made_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='product_by')
    image = models.ImageField()
    order_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    picked = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='item_picked')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your form_valid method is quite strange. Among other things, you set the item to `self.item`, which isn't used anywhere and certainly isn't set on the created instance. Additionally, you create and save the object there directly, but then call the superclass method which will do it again without your additions.

Instead you should set all these attributes on `form.instance`, then let the super method do the saving:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.review_from = self.request.user
    form.instance.item = OrderItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
    form.instance.review_for = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: +1 but it might be worth noting that `OrderItem` should first be `filter`ed to only include items actually purchased by the user.

Comment: @DanielHepper The order history page shows OrderItems with the correct user, so when the request.user clicks on leave review. it chooses the correct item and the user that sold the item

Comment: @SamirTendulkar yes, but a malicious user can simply change the pk in the URL. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10-2017_A5-Broken_Access_Control

Comment: @DanielHepper I am using `form.instance.item = OrderItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
`  How do I `filter` and `get` in the same code

Comment: @DanielHepper thanks I fixed the code filtered to only include items actually purchased by the user
        `if self.request.user in form.instance.item.order.buyer:`
           ` form.instance.review_for = User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs.get('username'))`
        `super().form_valid(form)`
        `return redirect('home')`